# multiple select query with same where clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, where-clause

I have two type of select statement with the same complicated where clause.

One - *Returns transaction detailed data*

```
select field_1, field_2, field_3, ... , field_30 from my_table where my_where_clause
```

Second - *Returns transaction data grouped by(distinct) merchants*

```
select distinct field_1, field_2, field_8 from my_table where my_where_clause
```

Statements are called separately.

**I want to simplify my code and not to repeat this complicated where clause in both statements without loosing performance**

In dynamic SQL it's possible but I don't want to use dynamic SQL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: dynamic sql might be an option

Comment: Yes it is, but I want to avoid dynamic SQL

Comment: The 2nd is derivable from the first, so inserting the first into a temp table and querying that may be an option.

Comment: In this case it will beatify my code but it also will affect on performance.

Comment: Maybe there is any way to simplify my code without affecting on performance.

Comment: @AlexK. - temporary tables can be performance bottlenecks. Any GTT solution needs to be benchmarked.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid dynamic SQL?

Comment: it's kind of hard to read

Comment: You mention PL/SQL. So what do you do with the queries' results in your PL/SQL procedure/function?

Answer (score 2):

**Suggestion:** you can try GROUPING SETS expression. 
 It allows you to selectively specify the set of groups that you want to create within a GROUP BY clause. In

In your case, you can specify 2 sets,  one group by set for all fields from 1 to 30 and another set for fields 1,2&8.
 Link- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40518_01/server.761/es_eql/src/reql_aggregation_grouping_sets.html

However, it will return the output of both the groups in a single resultset, not sure if this fits in your design.

Answer (score 1):

So you could encapsulate this statement, in a view or function, e,g,:

```
create or replace view view_1 as
   select field_1, field_2, field_3, ... , field_30 
   from my_table 
   where my_where_clause
```

Then your second query could be

```
 select distinct * from view_1;
```

Comment: I can't use VIEW because I have many parameters in my where clause. I can't use function because in this case I have to return Cursor  in sub function and Loop over it in my main function.

Comment: Thank you for comment, I added some details.

Comment: I want to simplify my code so that I don't have to write my complicated where cause in both statement. These queries are almost same.

Comment: I think now I got your point. I'm returning result of these queries from function (with cursor). This function is called from Java code. Was that what you are asking to write?

Comment: yes. please explain - in pseudo-code if necessary - how the two queries fit into "I have to return Cursor in sub function and Loop over it in my main function"

Answer (score 0):

You said that you are using this query from java. Try this.

```
create or replace function  get_cursor(p_type varchar2 default null/* other paramethers*/ ) return sys_refcursor
is 
result_curosr sys_refcursor; 
begin 
open result_curosr for 'select '||p_type||' object_type,status from user_objects' /* where clausele */ ;
return result_curosr;
end;
```

And usage of this from java.

```
Connection con = ...
    CallableStatement  callableStatement = con.prepareCall("declare  c sys_refcursor; begin  ? := get_cursor(?); end ; ");

    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1,  OracleTypes.CURSOR);

    callableStatement.setString(2, "Distinct"); // for distinct 
or 
    callableStatement.setNull(2, OracleTypes.VARCHAR); // for full results 
    callableStatement.executeUpdate();
    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);
    while(rs.next()) {
        System.err.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
    rs.close();

        con.close();
```

Other solution. 
Add one more parameter and do simple deduplication using all columns from query. But i don't see any advantages.

```
select object_type,status from 
(select object_type,status, row_number() over( partition by object_type,status order by 1) rn from user_objects /* your_where_clusue */
) where rn = case when 'DISTIINCT'/* <- paramete here :isDistinct */  = 'DISTIINCT' then 1 else rn end;
```

Comment: This is solution using dynamic SQL. I don't want to use dynamic SQL

Comment: Ok, Without dynamic sql , just simple query but performance probably will be worse.

Answer (score 0):

You can make dynamic SQL more readable by using multi-line strings, alternative quotes, and templates.

```
declare
    v_select varchar2(32767);
    v_where  varchar2(32767);
    v_code   varchar2(32767) := '
            ##SELECT##
            ##WHERE##
    ';
begin
    --Populate the clauses.
    if ... then
        v_select := 'select field_1, field_2, field_3, ... , field_30 from my_table';
    else
        v_select := 'select distinct field_1, field_2, field_8 from my_table';
    end if;

    if ... then
        v_where :=
        q'[
            where field_1 = 'foo'
                and field_2 = :bind1
                ...
        ]';
    else
        v_where :=
        q'[
            where field_2 = 'bar'
                and field_2 = :bind2
                ...
        ]';
    end if;

    --Fill in the code.
    v_code := replace(v_code, '##SELECT##', v_select);
    v_code := replace(v_code, '##WHERE##', v_where);

    --Print the code to check the formatting.  Remove after testing.
    dbms_output.put_line(v_code);

    --Run it.
    execute immediate v_code using ...;
end;
/
```

It's not perfect but it prevents ugly concatenation.  And it's much better than the anti-patterns needed to avoid dynamic SQL at all costs.  In most languages features like polymorphism and reflection are better than dynamic code.  PL/SQL does not have good support for those advanced features so it's usually better to build the code as a string.